# AFNetworking and 404

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to post to a URL using AFNetworking and no matter what I do I keep getting the error:

```
Error Code: -1011 - Expected status code in (200-299), got 404
```

My code is as follows:

```
NSString *baseurl = @"http://mysiteurl";

NSString *path = @"/user/register/";

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseurl]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
//[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"myusername" password:@"mypassword"];

[client postPath:path parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_userName,@"user", _email, @"email",_password,@"password", nil] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

    //NSLog(@"sjson: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"entries"]);
    NSLog(@"sjson: %@", JSON);        
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error Code: %i - %@",[error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

When I go to `http://mysiteurl/user/register/` directly I am able to see JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I go to `http://mysiteurl/user/register/` directly I am able to see JSON.

If you're doing this through a browser, you are making a `GET` request, whereas in your code, you are making a `POST` request.

A 404 is not just the visible address, it includes the HTTP method as well. You need to make sure that your server responds to a `POST` at `http://mysiteurl/user/register/`. Depending on your framework (e.g. Rails), you may have to add `[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/json"]` to get the correct route.

Answer (score 0):

i usually use [client getPath: parameters:params success:] not Post but i guess this will work for both cases since your response is in a JSON format too

add these two lines

```
[client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/json"];
```

before

```
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```